# How to run python scripts in XAMPP on mac?

Tags: python, ajax, xampp

I have a ajax call being make to a python script.But instead of executing the code the call just prints the raw code.

I'm using xampp installed on mac.

What I did:
[edited the following line in httpd.conf]
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py

My python script present in htdocs is:

#/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

print("Hello World!")

Comment: Can you post an [mcve].